# Getting 502 Bad Gateway Error in CloudFront AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, bucket

Hello This is my Website.
www.giftdays.jp Which is insecured as its older SSL certificate has expired and is the reason I switched to AWS . 
Here is what I did step by step.

1) Issued a certificate aws cert manager method. It has been issued and status are OK and all green

2)Create a bucket inside s3 and set permission to public access + set properties(Static website hosting) to redirect requests to my domain which is www.giftdays.jp

3) Create a cloudfront distribution linking my issued aws certificate and s3 bucket.

Here is the result:

1)S3 bucket links shows XML error.

2)which leads to cloudfront error same as xml

3) Site is not secured.

Few keypoints:

I also did route to redirect dns to s3 link which results in same xml error page, thats why I have removed it from route 53 settings. 
Can anyone help me where am i going wrong. 
I just want to make my site secured.

[Redirect Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4NnF.jpg)

**Error:**

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
 <ListBucketResult xmlns="s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">; <Name>giftdays</Name> <Prefix/> <Marker/> <MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys> <IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated> </ListBucketResult>
```

Comment: Can you post redirect rules of s3?

Comment: @SudharsanSivasankaran I have attached the screenshot of redirect just now in main post.

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the error screenshots as well.

Comment: @kintuparantuThe Error I get after clicking bucket link or cloudfront link is :-

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ListBucketResult xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<Name>giftdays</Name>
<Prefix/>
<Marker/>
<MaxKeys>1000</MaxKeys>
<IsTruncated>false</IsTruncated>
</ListBucketResult>